# Rest-assured is making an extra call

Tags: rest, api, rest-assured

I am testing REST API using [rest-assured](http://rest-assured.io/). When I send POST request it looks like rest-assured is making extra call. Here is the output from /var/log/httpd/access_log:

```
11.31.41.111 - - [26/Nov/2019:19:39:14 +0000] "POST /rest/v1/contact HTTP/1.1" 401 340 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_221)"
11.31.41.111 - - [26/Nov/2019:19:39:14 +0000] "POST /rest/v1/contact HTTP/1.1" 200 515 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_221)"
```

When I send exactly same request using Postman, access log shows only one request comes to the server:

```
11.31.41.111 - - [26/Nov/2019:19:40:44 +0000] "POST /rest/v1/contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 529 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0"
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think rest assured first authenticate you based on the request. And the postman doesn't. That is why, you can see 401 for unauthorized code for every hit through rest assured for any requests.

Comment: When building request specification in RestAssured try using `.preemptive()` to avoid 1st request

Comment: @bhusak Thank you. Your solution worked. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: In case someone else will want to read more about the way that rest-assured does the auth, read Preemptive Basic Authentication and Challenged Basic Authentication sections [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#basic-authentication).

Comment: @sen4ik glad it helped! added an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Preemptive Authentication when building RestAssured request specification. Here's an example:

```
RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password")
      .when().get("http://example.com")
      .then().statusCode(200);
```